# Corebird "Request Pin" buton not working

Tags: 16.10

I'm trying to make Corebird work but when I press the Request Pin button nothing happens, please help me!
I'm using Ubuntu 16.10
Thanks!!
[image]

Comment: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/01/essential-guide-to-corebird-twitter-app-for-linux "First run account wizard" chapter.

Comment: Hi! That's what I'm doing, the very first step is to open the app and request the pin but when you press the button the web browser won't open :(